# Configuring nginx to forward to ASP.NET Core 6 application - Resolver error

Tags: nginx, redirect, resolver

I am configuring **nginx** for windows to forward requests to an ASP.NET Core 6.0 app runing in Kestrel

I put this directive in nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /PassThrough/ {
        rewrite ^/PassThrough(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://$host:5171;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

which should redirect http://localhost/Passthrough to http://localhost:5171
It does not, the logged error is

```
no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost,...
```

hitting http://localhost:5171 directly DOES work

I tried adding resolver directive and specifying server_name but that did not help.
If in the browser I specify

```
http://127.0.0.1/Passthrough
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/Passthrough
```

It also WORKS. But that is not something I can live with.

Things I tried as a resolver are 127.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8 (google) and 192.168.0.1 (default gateway)